# HDFS files under data/hbase/oldWALs folder growing too much

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

Our HDFS file system is growing a lot. Here is the result after I run **hdfs dfs -du -h  /data/hbase**, you can see most of the spaces are in "oldWALs" folder:

```
    0        0        /data/hbase/.tmp
    0        0        /data/hbase/MasterProcWALs
    2.0 G    5.0 G    /data/hbase/WALs
    241.3 M  482.5 M  /data/hbase/archive
    29.5 G   59.0 G   /data/hbase/data
    42       84       /data/hbase/hbase.id
    7        14       /data/hbase/hbase.version
    666.3 G  1.3 T    /data/hbase/oldWALs
```

I've disabled the Hbase replication:

```
    <property>
        <name>hbase.replication</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
```

And the logcleaner interval is set to 5 minutes:

```
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master.logcleaner.ttl</name>
        <value>300000</value>
    </property>
```

But the folder keeps on increasing about 100GB daily.

Can I just delete the folder manually? If not How can I clean the folder to save disk spaces?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you removed peers? If yes, the oldWALs should be cleared by chore. As you have enabled replication, any WAL which is yet to be replicated will be held back under oldWALs.

Comment: the hbase.replication was set to false when I set up the cluster. I've tried to run list_peers and it showed that : hbase.replication isn't true, please enable it in order to use replication. I will try to delete the folder manually and let you know the result.